How can I Interact with a select element using selenium or puppeteer
I'm trying so select a value from this dropdown using puppeteer and selenium, have tried every method under the sun and it doesn't seem to work. When using selenium I have tried this:
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import time

driver = webdriver.Chrome()

# Open the delay repay form
driver.get("https://delayrepay.eastmidlandsrailway.co.uk/index.cfm?action=myclaims.add")

# Accept cookies
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '.btn.btn-default'))).click()
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '.cc-btn.cc-dismiss'))).click()

select_element = driver.find_element(By.NAME, 'txtTitle')

# Create the Select instance and select the option by value
select = Select(select_element)
time.sleep(2)
select.select_by_visible_text('Mr')

and end up running into a timeout error as the element doesn't get selected.
This is the select element:
<select name="txtTitle" id="txtTitle" class="s-hidden">

Tt can be found on this page https://delayrepay.eastmidlandsrailway.co.uk/index.cfm?action=myclaims.add
